# ¿Cómo realizar suma sobre condiciones encadenadas con Google Sheets?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando de realizar una suma de gastos agrupados por tipo.

Tengo en una hoja de calculo dos columnas, una llamada cantidad y otra llamada tipo de gasto. Dentro de la misma hoja en otra pestaña tengo una tabla que tiene las columas tipo de gasto y tipo general.

Por ejemplo dentro de tipo general tengo por ejemplo gasto variable y gasto fijo, de gasto fijo hay varios tipos de gasto (Alquiler, telefono..).

**TABLA1**

```
   Cantidad        |   Tipo de gasto
   __________________________________
   700             |   Alquiler
   150             |   Comida
```

**TABLA2**

```
   Tipo de gasto   |   Tipo general
   __________________________________
   Alquiler        |   Gasto fijo
   Internet        |   Gasto fijo
   Comida          |   Gasto variable
   Luz             |   Gasto variable
```

Lo que quiero es conseguir tener en una celda la suma de todos los gastos asociados a gasto fijo y todos los gastos asociados a gasto variable. Sin tener que estar poniendo uno a uno todos los que hay dentro de la formula.

Por más que intento realizar una fórmula para la obtención de este propósito no lo consigo. He estado mirando como realizarlo utilizando SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO, lo que más se asemeja a lo que quiero hacer sería emplear las siguientes fórmulas:

**Para fijo**

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(CANTIDAD2:CANTIDAD;
                   TIPODEGASTO2:TIPODEGASTO;
                   TABLAGASTO!TIPODEGASTO2:TIPODEGASTO3)
```

**Para variable**

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(CANTIDAD2:CANTIDAD;
                   TIPODEGASTO2:TIPODEGASTO;
                   TABLAGASTO!TIPODEGASTO4:TIPODEGASTO5)
```

No obstante eso me produce un error mostrándome 0.

También he investigado como hacerlo con un script de Google, ya que con un triple bucle se podría hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
suma := 0
for ( i := 0 ; i < len( A ); i++ ){

    for ( j := 0 ; j < len( C ); j++ ){

        for ( k := 0; k < len( D ); k++ ) {

            if B[ i ] == C[ j ] && C[ j ] == D[ k ] {
                suma = suma + A[ i ]
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

El problema de esto es que consume demasiado tiempo realizando el cálculo cada vez que abro la hoja de cálculo, ya que está llena de datos.

Comment: Muy bien, nos has dicho lo que quieres conseguir. Falta que incluyas una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado para conseguirlo así como señalar de forma específica la parte en la que te has quedado atorado. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Hola Rubén, tienes toda la razón, ahora mismo me pongo a modificarlo, gracias!

Comment: Lo que tengo como solución momentanea es poner alado de tipo de gasto las siglas del tipo general, por ejemplo "Alquiler GF", de tal forma que ahora cuando hago el sumar.si.conjunto, la condición de match que pongo es que contenga "*GF*", pero no me termina de convencer está solución.

Comment: Sería mejor que usaras la notación que corresponde a las hojas de cálculo de Google y a Google Apps Script, por ejemplo para las referencias se usa la notación `A1`, aunque también está la posibilidad de usar nombres de rango. Una notación como `CANTIDAD2:CANTIDAD` no es soportada en las hojas de cálculo de Google. En cuanto a la notación de asignación de literales u objetos a nombres de variables, en Google Apps Script, el cual está basado en JavaScript se usa `=` en lugar de `:=`, `len` no es una función incluida en Apps Script/JS, la condición del if debe ir entre paréntesis, etc.

Comment: Si te preocupa el desempeño deberías mencionar el volumen de datos a manejar por la fórmula o script aunque lo mejor sería hacer la pregunta lo más acotada posible para resolver una cosa a la vez porque de lo contrario se correría el riesgo de hacer la pregunta demasiado amplia. Es decir, primero encontrar una fórmula, luego evaluar su desempeño y si no fuera aceptable, realizar una nueva pregunta enfocada en la optimización de la fórmula encontrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se tienen dos tablas una para los elementos y otra para clasificarlos y se desea hacer cálculos con base en la clasificación, lo primero es hacer una tabla de datos para análisis en la forma de tabla simple, ya sea que la muestres en un rango de la hoja de cálculo o lo manejes como una fórmula anidada o matriz en notación `{}`

La tabla simple quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
   Cantidad        |   Tipo de gasto  |  Tipo general
   ________________________________________________________
   700             |   Alquiler       |  Gasto fijo
   150             |   Comida         |  Gasto variable
```

Para lograr lo anterior existen varias funciones que pueden ayudar como `BUSCARV` y la combinación de `INDICE` y `COINCIDIR`. En lo personal prefiero la segunda porque se dice que es más rápida que la primera.

Suponiendo que la tabla 1 está en `'Tabla 1'!$A$1:$B$3` y que la tabla 2 está en `'Tabla 2'!$A$1:$B$4`, una de las posibles formas para crear la tabla simple sería

En `'Tabla 3'!A1` agrega

```
={'Tabla 1'!$A$1:$B$3}
```

En `'Tabla 3'!C1` agrega

```
=INDICE('Tabla 2'!$B$1:$B$4,COINCIDIR($B1,'Tabla 2'!$A$1:$A$4,0)
```

y luego rellenas hacia abajo para obtener el tipo general para todos los elementos de la tabla 1.

Ya una vez que tienes la tabla simple para análisis, puedes aplicar funciones como `SUMA.SI.CONJUNTO`.

Lo anterior se puede optimizar sacando provecho de características de la hoja de cálculo de Google como ArrayFormula y otras funciones pero el propósito de lo anterior es mostrar la aplicación conceptos básicos del manejo de hojas de cálculo las cuales usan un tipo de pensamiento diferente al usado al programar en lenguajes como C#, JavaScript o SQL.

Comment: Conseguí lo que quería gracias a tu ayuda, ¡muchísimas gracias Rubén!, ¡así como gracias por la ayuda en la formulación de la pregunta!